# Application doesn't move to front when given focus from Task bar

Tags: vb.net, forms, focus, taskbar

I have an application that I'm running in debug to check out a piece of functionality I just added. As I was doing this I discovered the application does not move to the front when it's portion of the Task Bar is clicked.

This only seems to occur when I have one of the "child" (not technically an MDI child) forms open to display status of a task the user has initiated.

That child form is NOT present on the Task Bar (the idea being it's part of the same application so it shouldn't get it's own slot on the task bar).

Any ideas what the cause may be?

EDIT: Trying to elaborate a little. The issue is this, I'll have the application up & running, open a different program (Excel, Chrome, etc.) and that new window will appear over my app. I will then click my app's icon in the task bar. It appears to get focus, but the window does not move to the front, Excel (or whatever) is still on top of it. The only way to actually see my application is to minimize/close any other programs running on that screen.

Comment: I don't understand .. but check if your "child form" is modal and wait for some action

Comment: The form is definitely modal (call with ShowDialog) as I don't want the user to be able to do anything else while the status window is open. Edited my original question to try and clarify the issue.

Comment: Hmm, needed to tweak the application a little to make the statusing a little more meaningful on one particularly long running use case. Anyway, not sure if it's indirectly a result of the changes I made (doubtful) or just had a gremlin yesterday, but now I can get the window to move to the front as expected.  If anyone has any ideas what might have been causing this I'd still like to hear though. Gremlins do tend to come back, and "fixed indirectly" in my experience means "probably not fixed in all cases".

Answer (score 0):

use in form Designer

```
Form1.Topmost = True
```

See the corresponding MSDN.
    A topmost form is a form that overlaps all the other (non-topmost) forms even if it is not the active or foreground form. Topmost forms are always displayed at the highest point in the z-order of the windows on the desktop. You can use this property to create a form that is always displayed in your application, such as a Find and Replace tool window.

Comment: I get what you're getting at, but the issue isn't that the form never shows at the top (it correctly is on top when it opens).

Comment: (wouldn't let me edit my original comment) The issue is when the application regains focus it wasn't moving to the front of other applications that didn't have TopMost = True (i.e. just about everything other than the TaskManager)

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/169494 >>  "After you minimize a program, clicking the program's button on the taskbar may not restore or maximize the program. If you use the right mouse button to click the program's button on the taskbar, the Restore or Maximize command is available on the context menu for the program. "

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/377279/windows-7-cant-reopen-minimised-window-on-taskbar-preview-ok

Comment: @Crisit No minimizing, just opened another application so that took focus and moved to front. Is the theme issue you refer to intermittent? If not could you point me somewhere I can read up on the specifics. As I indicated, I'm not seeing the issue anymore so it seems like it's rarer than not, which leads me to say "Whatever" and move on.